# JQuery fadeOut then load

Tags: jquery

I'm fairly new to JQuery and I am having a problem with fading out and then loading afterwards.

My code is:

```
$("#refresh").live("click", function() {
    $("#postbit").fadeOut("slow");
       $("#postbit").load('load.php').fadeIn("slow");
    return false;
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It works fine if I don't have the fadeOut before and just have it load. But is there a way to make it first fadeOut and then having it fadeIn slowly :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery 1.7 or higher (probably, if you're new) you shouldn't use `.live` anymore since not only is it bad, but it will also be removed in later versions.  [`return false` from events is also bad](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/)

```
// Change this to the known parent of #refresh
// Do you even need delegation?
$("#refresh").closest('*').on('click', '#refresh', function (e) {

   // Callback to fadeOut (after fadeOut): load
   $("#postbit").fadeOut('slow', function () {

      // So you can reference this element without selector later
      var $this = $(this);

      // Callback to load -- takes place after load completes
      $this.load('load.php', function () {
         $this.fadeIn('slow');
      });
   });

   // Prevent click from doing whatever it would normally do on #refresh
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I didn't know `return false;` was bad lol.

Answer (score 3):

`.fadeOut()`, like many other jQuery functions, allows you to specify a callback function that is executed *after* the animation has finished:

```
$("#refresh").live("click", function() {
    $("#postbit").fadeOut("slow", function() {
       $("#postbit").load('load.php').fadeIn("slow");
    });

    return false;
});
```

This will execute the code inside the anonymous function (the second arfument of `.fadeOut()`) once the fade out animation has finished.

---

As an aside, you should no longer be using `.live()` as it's deprecated in favour of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).